# DirectX 11 and FreeType

Tags: c++, directx, freetype

Has anyone ever integrated FreeType with DirectX 11 for font rendering? The only article I seem to find is [DirectX 11 Font Rendering](https://isometrictiger.wordpress.com/2011/01/14/font-rendering-in-direct3d-11/). I can't seem to match the correct DXGI_FORMAT for rendering the grayscale bitmap that FreeType creates for a glyph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's three ways to handle greyscale textures in Direct3D 11:

**Option (1)**: You can use an RGB format and replicate the channels. For example, you'd use `DXGI_R8G8B8A8_UNORM` and set R,G,B to the single monochrome channel and the A to all opaque (0xFF). You can handle Monochrome + Alpha (2 channel) data the same way.

> This conversion is supported when loading `.DDS` luminance formats (`D3DFMT_L8`, `D3DFMT_L8A8`) by [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex) library and the [texconv](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/Texconv) command-line tool with the `-xlum` switch.

This makes the texture up to 4 times larger in memory, but easily integrates using standard shaders.

**Option (2)**: You keep the monochrome texture as a single channel using `DXGI_FORMAT_R8_UNORM` as your format. You then render using a custom shader which replicates the red channel to RGB at runtime.

This is in fact what the tutorial blog post you linked to is doing:

```
///////// PIXEL SHADER
float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD0) : SV_Target0
{
    return float4(Decal.Sample(Bilinear, uv).rrr, 1.f);
}
```

For Monochrome + Alpha (2-channel) you'd use `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8_UNORM` and then your custom shader would use `.rrrg` as the swizzle.

**Option (3)**: You can compress the monochrome data to the `DXGI_FORMAT_BC2` format using a custom encoder. This is implemented in [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK)'s [MakeSpriteFont](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/MakeSpriteFont) tool when using `/TextureFormat:CompressedMono`

```
// CompressBlock (16 pixels (4x4 block) stored as 16 bytes)
long alphaBits = 0; 
int rgbBits = 0; 

int pixelCount = 0;

for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) 
{ 
    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) 
    { 
        long alpha; 
        int rgb; 

        // This is the single monochrome channel
        int value = bitmapData[blockX + x, blockY + y];

        if (options.NoPremultiply) 
        { 
            // If we are not premultiplied, RGB is always white and we have 4 bit alpha. 
            alpha = value >> 4; 
            rgb = 0; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            // For premultiplied encoding, quantize the source value to 2 bit precision. 
            if (value < 256 / 6) 
            { 
                alpha = 0; 
                rgb = 1; 
            } 
            else if (value < 256 / 2) 
            { 
                alpha = 5; 
                rgb = 3; 
            } 
            else if (value < 256 * 5 / 6) 
            { 
                alpha = 10; 
                rgb = 2; 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                alpha = 15; 
                rgb = 0; 
            } 
        } 

        // Add this pixel to the alpha and RGB bit masks. 
        alphaBits |= alpha << (pixelCount * 4); 
        rgbBits |= rgb << (pixelCount * 2); 

        pixelCount++;
    } 
} 

// The resulting BC2 block is:
// uint64_t = alphaBits
// uint16_t = 0xFFFF
// uint16_t = 0x0
// uint32_t = rgbBits
```

The resulting texture is then rendered using a standard alpha-blending shader. Since it uses 1 byte per pixel, this is effectively the same size as if you were using `DXGI_FORMAT_R8_UNORM`.

This technique does not work for 2-channel data, but works great for alpha-blended monochrome images like font glyphs.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Chuck! Option #2 is more inline with what I was needing. I thought that DXGI_FORMAT_R8_UNORM  was the correct format, but wasn't sure. I needed to also update my pixel shader a bit to correctly swizzle across RGB.